# $n$ vertices from a regular polygon with $2n$ sides are red and the other $n$ vertices are blue.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, contest-math, generating-functions

> $n$ vertices from a regular polygon with $2n$ sides are chosen and colored red. The other $n$ vertices are colored blue. Afterwards, the $\binom{n}{2}$ lengths of the segments formed with all pairs of red vertices are ordered in a non-decreasing sequence, and the same procedure is done with the $\binom{n}{2}$ lengths of the segments formed with all pairs of blue vertices. Prove that both sequences are identical.

Say $\mathcal{R}=\{r_1,r_2,...r_n\}$ the set of red vertices and $\mathcal{B}=\{b_1,b_2,...b_n\}$ the set of blue vertices.
Let $$R(x) = \sum _{i=1}^{n} x^{r_i}\;\;\;\wedge \;\;\; B(x) = \sum _{i=1}^{n} x^{b_i}$$
then we have to prove that $$B(x)B({1\over x}) = R(x)R({1\over x})$$ 
where the exponents are taken modulo $2n$.

**Is this reasonable aproach?**

Comment: not sure if this helps, but I think it is sufficient to prove that there exists an axis of symmetry in the coloured polygon

Comment: There doesn't have to be an axis of symmetry.  You could have RRRBRRBBBB, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace each exponent in $R(x)R(1/x)$ and $B(x)B(1/x)$ by its remainder modulo $2n$, you obtain two polynomials with degrees at most $2n-1$. For proving that the two polynomials are identical, it is sufficient to verify that they have equal values at $2n$ points, for example, at the $2n$th complex roots of unity.

Let $\omega_k=e^{k\pi i/n}$ for $k=0,2,\ldots,2n-1$.

At $\omega_0=1$ we have $R(1)^2=B(1)^2=n^2$, done.

If $1\le k\le 2n-1$ then $R(\omega_k)+B(\omega_k)=\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}\omega_k^j=0$, so $R(\omega_k)=-B(\omega_k)$. Then 
$$
R(\omega_k) R(1/\omega_k) = 
R(\omega_k) R(\omega_{2n-k}) = 
\big(-B(\omega_k)\big) \big(-B(\omega_{2n-k})\big) = 
B(\omega_k) B(\omega_{2n-k}) = 
B(\omega_k) B(1/\omega_k).
$$

Answer (score 5):

We will refer to the decagon with vertices colored $RRRBRRBBBB$ as an example in what follows.  First consider the sides of the decagon, which are the shortest length.  Go around the decagon and count how many sides have ends with different colors, calling the number $k$, which must be even. In our example there are four.  Then there are $n$ red vertices grouped into $\frac k2$ groups.  The number of red-red edges is $n-\frac k2$, as is the number of blue-blue edges.  Here $k=4$ and the number of red-red or blue-blue edges is three.

That argument works for any length that results from a vertex spacing that is coprime to $2n$, so for our example segments that result from vertices three apart.  If you draw the segments you get a ten pointed star that is just another order to look at the vertices.  For a spacing of two vertices you get two pentagons.  In our example one is $RRRBB$ and one is $RBRBB$.  Again if you look at the number of red-blue edges, here $6$, you have $\frac 62$ groups of red vertices and $n-\frac k2=2$ red-red or blue-blue edges.

This extends to the diameters.  There are $k$ red-blue diameters, then $n-\frac k2$ red-red or blue-blue diameters.  Here $k=6$ and there are two red-red and two blue-blue diameters.

Added:  a much simpler approach.  Consider all the segments of a given length other than the diameter.  There are $2n$ of them.  $2n$ of the ends are red and $2n$ are blue.  Let there be $k$ that have one red end and one blue end.  There are $2n-k$ red ends unaccounted for, so there must be $\frac 12(2n-k)$ segments with both ends red and the same number with both ends blue.  For the diameters there are $n$ of them, with $n$ red ends and $n$ blue ends.  Again, let $k$ of them have one red and one blue end.  There must be $\frac 12(n-k)$ with red at both ends and the same number with blue at both ends.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an invariant approach.

Let $b$ and $r$ be vertices colored blue and red respectively, and suppose we interchange the colors of $b$ and $r$.  For a given length $\ell$, the segments of length $\ell$ passing through $b$ and $r$ are in one-to-one correspondence.  Let two such corresponding segments be $bv_b$ and $rv_r$ respectively.  The corresponding table shows the possible colorings, before and after, where $b'$ and $r'$ are the recolored $b$ and $r$.

$$
\begin{array}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
 v_b & v_r & bv_b & rv_r & b'v_b & r'v_r\\
 \hline  
 B & B & BB & RB &RB &BB \\ 
 B & R & BB & RR & RB & BR \\ 
 R & B & BR & RB & RR & BB \\
 R & R & BR & RR &RR & BR\\
\hline 
\end{array}
$$

In the first and fourth lines, we see that the count of monochrome edges is unchanged.    In the second line the red-red and blue-blue counts have each decreased by $1$.  In the third line, they have each increased by $1$.

Now, if the vertices of the polygon are alternately colored red and blue, then the monochrome counts are the same, by symmetry.  Since any permutation of the colors can be achieved by exchanging the colors of two differently-colored vertices, the foregoing shows that the counts are the same no matter how the vertices are colored.

**EDIT**

The line segment $br$ should never be taken into account, of course.

Comment: @Aqua Isn't this true by symmetry?  Every vertex of a regular polygon looks like every other one, and will have either one or two vertices of length $\ell$ incident on it.

Comment: @Aqua Either I don't understand what you're saying, or you don't understand what I'm saying.  I'm not talking about the colors at all in the context of the segment lengths.  $r$ and $b$ are just two vertices that happen to be colored differently, but they each have $2n-1$ segments incident on them, and the lengths are the same in both cases.